# dhtmlxForm text style settings

Tags: forms, styles, dhtmlx

I use the next html:

```
<input type = "text" id = "my_id" style = "text-align: right; color: #ff0000">
```

How to set the "text-align, color" property values of the above on dhtmlxForm?
I think probably something like a set way, how do I correct?

```
{type: "input", name: "my_id", text-align:"right", color: "#ff0000" },
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "className" attribut for form items [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/form__controls_list.html#inputtextarea)
You can add your style setting there